# Unable to see Snowflake conn_id in AirFlow Adhoc Query

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-scheduler

Has anyone been successfully able to run Snowflake & snowflake-connector-python on AirFlow?
I am trying to install it using these commands

`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org snowflake-sqlalchemy`

`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org apache-airflow[snowflake]`

But I am unable to get it working.
I don't see any errors/issues in the installation process but when I try to use Adhoc Query feature after establishing the connection, I don't see the conn_id for my snowflake connections. While I am able to see conn_ids for my other mssql connections.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more specific, what is the error message you are getting, at what step?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I have added the error details.

Comment: I've used the snowflake connector for Python quite a bit without issue. What version of Python did you use to install Airflow?

Comment: @SimonD, I am using Python 3.7. I was able to get snowflake connector Python installed recently but now I am having hard time creating the snowflake connection in AirFlow UI. I am following the connection instructions from this link [link](https://itnext.io/connect-apache-airflow-to-snowflake-data-warehouse-37936a9edfa1) but couldn't see the connection in AdHoc query dropdown.

Comment: @SimonD, apart from snowflake-connector-python, are there any other dependencies that need to be installed? The link I provided above is asking to install snowflake-sqlalchemy.

Comment: What error are you seeing now? Yes you'll need to install snowflake-sqlalchemy if you intend to use the adhoc query tool in airflow. I think I've lost track of what you're trying to do though.. if you've installed the snowflake connector what is your issue now?

Comment: @SimonD I installed snowflake-sqlalchemy as you suggested and also set up the connection under admin->connection. But I am unable to see my connection_id in Adhoc Query. Also when I listed of all the installed python packages, I didn't see snowflake-connector-python. Does installing snowflake-sqlalchemy automatically installs snowflake-connector-python or does it need to be installed separately?